# reactNative.TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground is not a function

Tags: git, react-native, floating-action-button, action-button

I just changed the mac i'm using. So i imported my project from Git(node modules of course was in the git.ignore file ). The project is running perfectly fine with the old mac but I get this error when running it on the new mac.

```
_reactNative.TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground is not a function. (In '_reactNative.TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()', '_reactNative.TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground' is undefined)]
```

Comment: What RN version and NPM packages are you using? I'm having a similar error, and am curious to see what overlap there is.

Comment: "react": "~15.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.41.2",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.6.0"                                                                                                                react-native-cli: 2.0.1
npm 4.0.5

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this issue, if you're using `react-native-action-button`: https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button/issues/144

If not, maybe it will point you in the right direction.